# WP admin Screen Issue

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP website when I logged into admin panel im seeing the screen as in the image [image]

I don't know what's wrong, I updated the WP to the latest version.

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

**Problem : Admin Css not loading**

WordPress admin CSS styles missing.
All the WordPress admin styles were not loading.

**Solution**

Step :1 Download a wordpress zip file.

Step :2 Extract it

Step :3 keep wp-content and your database, just reinstall the core files

Step :4  Clear your browser cache & Login to admin again. (Use Incognito mode in chrome)

**Updated Answer**

**Problem : Admin Css not loading**

As mention in comment you have problem with plugin or theme that will not be support updated version.

Step to check why this happening.

Step 1 : Rename plugin folder and load website load site (if not solve)

Step 2 : Rename theme folder and load website (if not solve)

Step 3 : Rename both and check (if not solve)

If anything that break that will be detect.please check one by one activation plugin.

**Note** Please do this in localhost if your site is working on live.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130916/discussion-on-answer-by-vasim-vanzara-wp-admin-screen-issue).

Answer (score 0):

add this code in wp-config.php and try

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Comment: this is hack not solution